# How to find out version SQLite in Qt?

Tags: sqlite, qt4

I want to discover SQLite version in Qt 4.6.2 & 4.7.4
How to find out version SQLite in Qt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have direct access to the SQLite C API, call [`sqlite3_libversion()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/libversion.html).

If you have only SQL access, run the query [`SELECT sqlite_version();`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#sqlite_version).

Answer (score 1):

```
QSqlQuery query_version{mDatabase};
query_version.exec("select sqlite_version();");
query_version.next();
QString version = query_version.value("sqlite_version()").toString();
query_version.finish();

qDebug() << "SQLite version: " << version;
```